# How to do a function for every split string using string delimiters in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, split

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Split the String using a delimiter.
2. Use a function on each split string.
   Here is my 'implementation' so far:

```cpp
void for_each_split_line(char* str, char delim, std::function<void(char*)> fn) {
    char* line = (char*)"";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i]==delim) {
            fn(line);
            line = (char*)"";
        } else {
            size_t len = strlen(line);
            char* str2 = (char*)malloc(len+2);
            strcpy(str2, line);
            str2[len] = str[i];
            str2[len+1] = '\0';
            line = str2;
        }
    }
    fn(line);
}
```

**NOTE**: I don't use `strtok`, because for some reason it ignores any consequent delimiters, for e.g. "HELLo\n\nWORLD" becomes "HELLO\nWORLD", but I need that empty string in between as well, for my usecase.

I do not know what to do to make the code work for string delimiters. Is it possible to change the code so that it works with delimiters like " - ", etc.?

Comment: Since you're using C++, why not use `std::string`?  that'll get you the `substr` member function.

Comment: @StephenNewell Many of the libraries I use in my project are C based so it takes in char* only, and it's constantly irritating to convert between them. Plus I'm planning to port the library over to C soon. Also also, this can be a huge learning experience in disguise.

Comment: @Asadefa, I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you are citing `fopen`, when I'm not using files. Is there something about it that can make this easier for strings, could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisGeorge I accidentally cited fopen on the wrong question. I meant to do it on another one.

Comment: This is the use case for [`strsep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html), but that never got standardised, so it is not universally implemented. There are freely copyable shims, though.

Comment: @rici It works for me without using any additional libraries. What do you mean by 'freely copyable shims'? Sorry...

Comment: @ChrisGeorge: It's present on many systems and you don't need additional libraries to use it. (You may need to do something to ensure that the header declares it, particularly if you use a strict standard.) But it's not available on every system. A "shim" is an implementation of a library function which can be used on systems which lack the library function. A freely-copyable shim is one which doesn't have any restrictions on copying or using the code.

Comment: @rici Thanks, this helped a lot with this question!

Comment: @ChrisGeorge: In particular, it's available on Linux or any other environment which uses the GNU C library.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should look up `std:istringstream`, `std::ostringstream` and `std::getline`.  Also, `std::string` manages dynamic memory for you so you don't have worry about using `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: I'd get rid of references to the C language, since the C language doesn't support the `std` namespace.

Comment: If you want to maintain the C language aspect, research `strtok`, `strlen` and `sscanf`.